# How to track down the copy and move operations of files and folders?

Tags: files

I use drag and drop to copy and move files. One disadvantage of that is files might end up to the wrong places. So, let's say I copied/moved many files and folders to multiple different destinations.

How can I track down where everything ended up to make sure that everything was copied/moved to the right places?

Comment: But 'Undo' doesn't say where the files were copied to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is a "file system watcher".

## [iWatch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/iwatch) [image: Install iWatch]

> iWatch is a realtime filesystem monitoring program. It's a simple perl script to monitor changes in specific directories/files and send email notification immediately. It reads the dir/file list from xml config file and needs inotify support in kernel (Linux Kernel >= 2.6.13).

There are more but this seems the most simple method, is native to Ubuntu and uses inotify (so it does not hog the system).

iWatch comes in 2 methods:

1. command line
2. daemon

---

Some command line options for logging:

```
-m <email address>
   Specify the contact point's email address. Without this option, iwatch will 
   not send any email notification. 

-s <on|off>
   Enable or disable reports to the syslog (default is off/disabled)
```

---

[Some command line examples](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/documentation.html):

```
iwatch /tmp
```

monitor changes in /tmp directory with default events

```
iwatch -r -e access,create -m cahya@localhost -x /etc/mail /etc
```

monitor only access and create events in /etc directory recursively with /etc/mail as exception and send email notification to cahya@localhost.

```
iwatch -r -c "(w;ps -ef)|mail -s '%f was changed' cahya@localhost" /bin
```

monitor /bin directory recursively and execute the command.

```
iwatch -r -X '\.svn' ~/projects
```

monitor ~/projects directory recursively, but exclude any .svn directories inside. This can't be done with a normal '-x' option since '-x' can only exclude the defined path.

---

**[Example config file](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/documentation.html)** when using daemon mode mode. Logging is done with XML options in the configuration file:

```
<config>
  <guard email="myadmin@localhost" name="IWatch"></guard>
  <watchlist>
  <title>Public Website</title>
  <contactpoint email="webmaster@localhost" name="Web Master"/>
    <path type="single">/var/www/localhost/htdocs</path>
    <path type="single" syslog="on">/var/www/localhost/htdocs/About</path>
    <path type="recursive">/var/www/localhost/htdocs/Photos</path>
  </watchlist>
  <watchlist>
  <title>Operating System</title>
  <contactpoint email="admin@localhost" name="Administrator"/>
    <path type="recursive">/etc/apache2</path>
    <path type="single">/etc/passwd</path>
    <path type="recursive">/etc/mail</path>
    <path type="exception">/etc/mail/statistics</path>
    <path type="single" filter="shadow|passwd">/etc</path>
  </watchlist>
  <watchlist>
  <title>Only Test</title>
  <contactpoint email="root@localhost" name="Administrator"/>
    <path type="single" alert="off" exec="(w;ps -ef)|mail -s %f
      root@localhost">/tmp/dir1</path>
    <path type="single" events="access,close" alert="off" exec="(w;ps -ef)|mail -s %f
      root@localhost">/tmp/dir2</path>
    <path type="single" events="default,access" alert="off" exec="(w;ps -ef)|mail -s '%f is
      accessed' root@localhost">/tmp/dir3</path>
    <path type="single" events="all_events" alert="off">/tmp/dir4</path>
  </watchlist>
</config>
```

With this configuration, iwatch will monitor a single directory `/var/www/localhost/htdocs` without its sub directories, and any notification will be sent to the contact point webmaster@localhost. But it will monitor the whole directory tree of `/etc/apache2`, including any sub directories created later after the IWatch is started. You can use also create exceptions here if you don't want to get notification for a file or subdirectory inside the monitored directory.

Comment: OK, I did 'iwatch -d -v' in a terminal, then copied some files from a USB stick to a folder. Where can I find the recorded log?

Comment: If you used command line: where did you tell it to log too?

Comment: Now I understand, I have to make a config file first to use the daemon mode, or use the command line mode.

Comment: Yes and it is "or". Can not use both at the same time ;) Command line has an '-e' option that executes a command (how this is usefull not sure yet but I am guesssing it could also be used to copy the results to a file instead of just mailing or using syslog)

Comment: Do I have to run iwatch as sudo to enable it to write to syslog?

Comment: Is there something normal people can use?

Comment: @PavelNiedoba yes focus on the commands no the other parts Like `iwatch -r -X '\.svn' ~/projects`  is in theory all you need. It is just that everyone will have its own files to watch and different actions to check.

Comment: @Rinzwind I meant like "open software, install "this" and push "enquenue copy". its 2023 now